# Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Tag mismatch

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, android-emulator

Can't install Android studio - Android Studio Setup Wizard installed everything except Emulator and always shows error:
[image]
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m65DV.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved this problem by copying the link dl.google.com/android etc. (the one under Starting download...) and pasting in Chrome search bar - probably the problem was Internet connection

Comment: Welcome to SO! Feel free to 'accept' your own answer if your solution solves your own problem (even if it was just symptoms from a connectivity issue)

Answer (score 1):

This is mainaly network Error , change your network Provider like - if you use jio sim network , than change   airtal network or other wifi.

Answer (score 0):

i faced this problem, after i changed my isp it works perfactly.

Comment: That seems pretty dramatic